# How to turn all stone to TNT in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I really want to do a prank where I turn all stone to TNT. That way, in lava lakes the TNT will blow up. I just need to figure out how to do it. Which would it be best to use?

- `/fill`
- `/replaceitem`
- `/blockdata`
- `/setblock`
- something else?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: Well.. have you tried any of those commands to see what they do? Personally, Idk what they do, but I'm sure the wiki page has explanations for each to better suit your needs. This site works better when users show effort instead of just asking for help.

Comment: Do you **have to** turn stone into TNT?

Comment: Also, not to be captain obvious or anything, but wont people see the TNT literally everywhere? Id be surprised if someone actually fell for the prank. In fact, the second someone sets off a single TNT block, you'd more than likely crash the server (if you are playing on one) at the very least, your entire world would be completely levelled...

Comment: @Frank yes i have

Comment: @Fabian yes i do

Comment: @fishfinboy1 Apparently no, you did not make an attempt to solve it yourself. Because if you had just searched for "Minecraft replace blocks", the very first result would already have given you a very detailed step-by-step explanation.

Comment: Great!  *Then show us what you've tried*.  We've been over this multiple times.  Show some effort, please.

Comment: @Fabian :I (facepalm)

Comment: @KyleRone look at the question again

Answer (score 2):

```
/fill ~-15 ~-15 ~-15 ~15 ~15 ~15 tnt replace stone
```

Answer (score -1):

There is the bacteria mod where you can use the bacteria replacer colony and place it below the surface on a block of stone and put a block of TNT on top of the Bacteria replacer colony and then place a Redstone torch next to the colony both on the same y-coordinate and voila you have TNT.Although the bacteria will take time to accumulate every block of stone in the world.You also might want to destroy the Redstone as soon as possible so it does not activate any TNT.