# Primed tnt command help

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would like to summon primed tnt at a certain block in Minecraft or place a block above/next to an already placed block.

I have a gold block and I want to turn it into primed tnt, but don't know the coordinates. Is there a command that turns all of one type of block into primed tnt?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Answer (score 1):

The [command to summon](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#summon) primed tnt in 1.12.2 is:

```
/summon tnt <x> <y> <z>
```

You could also add data tag `Fuse` to increase the fused time:

```
/summon tnt <x> <y> <z> {Fuse:80}
```

Fuse specifies the number of ticks of delay before the explosion.  In this case, 80 ticks would be about 4 seconds which is the default fuse time for tnt after striking it with flint and steel.

---

Edit: Response to the edited question.  To my knowledge, there is no way to detect all gold blocks and replace them with tnt.  @Fabian gave [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/319504/186522) to a similar question.  It will only replace blocks around the executor and it will not be primed tnt as the replace option of the [fill command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#fill) does not have data tag argument.

You could add the [execute command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#execute) in a <kbd>Repeat</kbd><kbd>Unconditional</kbd><kbd>Always Active</kbd> command block to cause this to happen constantly.  Either around yourself or all players if multiplayer.  This would not be efficient and if executed for all players, would not allow players to place gold blocks.  They would have a system to convert gold blocks into tnt.  If you want to do this the command is:

```
execute @a ~ ~ ~ fill ~-15 ~-15 ~-15 ~15 ~15 ~15 tnt 0 replace gold_block
```

Comment: Say I have a gold block, and I want to turn it into primed tnt, but don't know the cordinates.  I want a command that turns all of one type of block into primed tnt. Make sense? I appreciate the help though!

Comment: You should put exactly what situation you have and the problem you are trying to solve in the question.