# (Java Minecraft 1.14) How to remove a specific amount of hunger points from a player?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

A heavily requested feature on a server I play on is Veinmeiner, however the server owner doesn't want to add mods. As a result, I'm writing a datapack for it. I've got most of it working, except for one part. I need to set the player's hunger based on how many blocks they mine. I know that /effect is an option, but I'm not sure how exactly to apply it based on the blocks mined. I know that mining 1 block adds .005 exhaustion points, but I don't know how much saturation and food that reduces. Is there a way to directly set/add to/remove from a player's hunger? If there is, what amount should I remove per some amount of blocks mined?

Comment: I'm always trying to improve my questions, but leaving a downvote with no explanation isn't super helpful. Next time, please leave a comment explaining how I could improve my question, so I can fix it so it is better.

Comment: Don't worry about single upvotes or downvotes, there's always someone who has a bad day or didn't read the question properly or whatever. It also goes the other way, I got three upvotes on this crappy answer: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/319503/how-to-turn-all-stone-to-tnt-in-minecraft/319504#319504

Comment: There is not attribute modifier for hunger (like there is for health) and you can't edit player NBT directly, so your only option is indeed `/effect`.

Comment: The wiki says it's 2 hunger points per effect level, but not in what time. I guess per second, I can't test it right now.

Comment: I have tried doing the hunger effect method, which works fine, but only when the player has no saturation (eg. when they have eaten past the full hunger bar), so this method does not work when the player has a full hunger bar.

Comment: @Quijibo So they would only lose hunger if they have 19 or less hunger points? Is there a way to give them saturation if they've got 20 hunger points so this method would work? I remember there being a saturation effect but does that change the saturation you're talking about?

Comment: @Nik3141 There is one effect called "saturation" and a hidden value called "saturation", which is related to hunger points (confusingly often also called "saturation points", because more hunger points mean you're less hungry). The saturation points prevent you from having hunger points removed at all, even with a hunger effect level 127 and while jumping and running like crazy, you still don't get any removed. The hunger system in Minecraft is quite complex and I guess you won't be able to control hunger as exactly as you would like.

Comment: So on the wiki for saturation (the effect) I see that a negative value removes saturation and food points. Does this mean that if I apply saturation to a player (rather than hunger) I can affect the hunger of those with 20 food points and full saturation?