# Cannot give an item that can only break redstone (1.14.2)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I am trying to `/give` myself a golden axe which can only break redstone.

```
/give @r minecraft:golden_axe{CanDestroy:["minecraft:redstone"]} 1 - Does not work
```

However in adventure mode it does not work.

I have also tried using "minecraft:redstone_dust", but to no avail

**But any other block works in adventure mode:**

```
/give @r minecraft:golden_axe{CanDestroy:["minecraft:oak_log"]} 1 - Works
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`redstone_wire`

[minecraft.gamepedia.com/Java_Edition_data_values](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Java_Edition_data_values)

Comment: didn't downvote, but it might be more helpful if you were to provide your answer as `/give @r minecraft:golden_axe{CanDestroy:["minecraft:redstone_wire"]} 1` (or whatever the full command should be)

Comment: Its okay if he did not provide the full command. I already know the syntax for it.

Comment: I tend to answer questions that show little effort with little effort myself. Another example is this one, which was upvoted three times for some reason: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/319503/how-to-turn-all-stone-to-tnt-in-minecraft/319504#319504